# Project 2013 custom cost field, project time-phased

Tags: ms-project-2013

I created a custom cost field (in Project 2013) called, "Labor Contract Amt" and would like to use the Cash Flow chart to compare "Cost" to "Labor Contract Amt" across any selected period of time. As custom fields are not available in the Time portion of this Project report, I am trying to export to Excel using the Cashflow Visual Report. When the field picker appears, I select the custom cost field "Labor Contract Amt", however the field does not appear in available fields.

Please advise on how to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Answered at: [Project 2013 - Custom cost field not visible in Time Report](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-project/project-2013-custom-cost-field-not-visible-in-time/03904dd1-8dea-4ddd-a6d4-7797a071cce8)

> I'm afraid custom fields are not timephased so they will not appear in
>   any of the Visual Reports.  Project does not know how to spread the
>   custom cost data.  The best I can recommend is to export the data
>   (Cost and the Custom Cost fields) to Excel and manually spread the
>   data.

If you have further questions, please keep the conversation going on the Answers site.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding your answer from the link to your answer on SE, in case of future link death.